# multiple classes in a single physical file on android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Right now I have to create a new physical file in eclipse android for every public class I create

For eg if I have the below 2 classes (System and Region) like this:

Region.java file:

```
package com.acrossair.tvguideuk;

public class Region
{
      public int RegionID;
      public String Name;
}
```

System.java file:

```
package com.acrossair.tvguideuk;

public class System
{
      public int SystemID;
      public String Name;
}
```

How can I simply create a file CustomObjects.java and have all of these custom classes in 1 single file?

Comment: In java you can only have one public top level class in each file. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You can have several classes in one file, but not public ones. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: only for code maintainability purposes. i dont like to see so many classes in my eclipse IDE :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create your custom objects as public inner classes of a `CustomObjects` class:

```
public class CustomObjects {
  public class Region {
    public int RegionID;
    public String Name;
  }
  public class System {
    public int SystemID;
    public String Name;
  }
}
```

But you couldn't use static members in the inner classes unless they were static themselves.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have 2 public classes defined in a single file. You however can have multiple classes defined in a file.

```
package com.acrossair.tvguideuk;

public class CustomObjects {}

class Region
{
      public int RegionID;
      public String Name;
}
class System
{
      public int SystemID;
      public String Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java multiple class are convert multiple class file.like if your file have 3 class then 3 .class files are generated by compiler.
but in android only one dex file are generated.